# Error trying to render new page after fetch request in Express

Tags: node.js, json, express, http, fetch

## Problem

I have set up an HTTP fetch request from the client side with some JSON data (a dataURL from a canvas), and I want to be able to access it from the server side and then render a new page that displays that dataURL. This is an Express only app (no client-side frameworks).

However, I keep getting an error. It would seem to me that there's something wrong with the JSON data or the way I handle it, but look at the code.

In Safari, it's `Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.`

In Chrome, it's `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

In Firefox, it's `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

## Code

### Client Side

I have an HTML canvas that I've converted into a dataURL and saved in a JSON object. That object gets sent to sendData.

If I get rid of the line `response.json()`, then I don't get the error. But I want to render a new page with the dataURL displayed in a paragraph tag.

```js
function sendData(input) {
    fetch('/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(input)
    })
    .then((response) => {
        response.json()
    })
}

//Saves dataURL as string
function saveData(input){
    var dataURL = input.toDataURL()
    data = { imageData: dataURL}
    sendData(data)
}
```

### Server Side

If I get rid of the line `res.render('images')`, I don't get the error, but, once again, I can't render the new page then. Also, this might be another issue, but Express is already not rendering the new page. Logging the `req.body.imageData` works.

```js
exports.submit_image = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body.imageData)
  res.render('images')
}
```

### Routes

And just in case this helps, here's the index.js in the routes directory

```js
router.get('/', index.get_index)
router.post('/', index.submit_image)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response? Also use the Network pane to inspect the response body. You’ll likely find that the response is an HTML document (probably an error page) rather than the expected JSON.

Comment: Are you getting the req.body.imageData ? are you able to log it out ?

Comment: @sideshowbarker The status code for the response is 200, which is odd. And yes, the response body is HTML.

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya Yes, logging the req.body.imageData works.

Comment: Why is the response body HTML? What are the contents?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I think the response body is HTML because on the server side code I have ```res.render('images')```. If I comment out this line, I get no response data. The contents of the HTML are from a pug file 'images'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js automatically handles rejected promises by logging them. You can suppress it using the following code. Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) page for more information about promises.

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', event => {
     event.preventDefault()
}, false)
```